# Image button with an accelerator key

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am trying to use the xaml below to define a Button that will:

- have an image
- have concatenated text, partly from an external resx & partly from a vm property
- have an accelerator key based on the first letter of the text

The markup below gives me the image and text, but doesn't work as an accelerator key (the "_" doesn't hide and Alt-A doesn't work).

How can I fix the markup to get accelerator key functionality?

---

Current markup and behavior

```
<Style x:Key="AddNewItemButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image Source="{resx:Resx ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=bullet_add}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                <TextBlock Text="_"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{resx:Resx ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=Subject_AddNew}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding AddNewItemCommand}" />
</Style>
```

[image]

## Update w/ HB's code

Nothing BUT the image:
[image]

```
<Style x:Key="AddNewItemButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="_{0} {1} {2}">
                <Binding Source="{resx:Resx ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=Add}"/>
                <Binding Source="{resx:Resx ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=New}"/>
                <Binding Path="Subject"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{resx:Resx ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=bullet_add}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding AddNewItemCommand}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm interested to know how your Resx syntax works?  I usually use something like Binding Source="{x:Static Properties:Resources.AddNew}"

Comment: @Phil. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AccessText with a multi-binding

```
    <Style x:Key="AddNewItemButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Source="{... your image}" Stretch="Uniform" />

                    <AccessText>
                        <AccessText.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}_{0} {1}">
                                <Binding Source="{... resources}"/>
                                <Binding Source="{Binding Subject}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </AccessText.Text>
                    </AccessText>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like [ContentPresenter.RecognizesAccessKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.recognizesaccesskey.aspx) is set to `false`.

Also, someone talks about it [here](http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-styled-button-does-not-display-access-key/).

Comment: Sounds useful but I have not been able to modify my code so far to try it - do you see how to do that?

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Adding "RecognizesAccessKey="True"" as attribute in the ContentPresenter tag worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Label control. It's designed for the cases where you have two controls, one which has an access key for triggering the second.

Comment: I knew about that one but wanted to see how to use the AccessText without the Label in this question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content` to that *combined* text, which can not be done in the template.

```
    <!-- (Resources changed for testing) -->
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="_{0} {1}">
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource Res_Add}"/>
                <Binding Path="Subject"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Res_Image}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: See updated post and the result of using this code - something is obviously not quite right. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl: I did not use compiled XAML, you may need to escape the `StringFormat` using `{}` i.e. `StringFormat="{}_{0} {1}"`. This approach definitely works though.